# Media files not showing on Debug False

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, django-media

I've just deployed a site with pythonanywhere, when I set to `DEBUG` mode to `False`, my media images dissapear, the path of my media folder is not found. I was asking myself what causes this issue and how I can resolve it ?

Here is how I configured my **settings** :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, with **pythonanywhere** I had to setup media on the static files handler like this  :

**path :** `/media/`

**directory :** `/home/<myusername>/<myproject>/media`

Then reload the domain name after setting `DEBUG` to `False`.

Comment: can you give more details? e.g. the source of the information and the config lines and commands you ended up using?

Comment: there is a built in static file handler in pythonanywhere, you can read more  [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles) about it.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is by design, Django doesn't serve static files in production mode. Serving many, potentially huge static files using Python will put a lot of stress on the server, while any of the common servers will handle that with ease.

Hence you need to serve them using Apache or nginx yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: Isn't `StaticFilesHandler` on wsgi from pythonanywhere serving the static files already ?