# Django cannot find my media folder while debug = False

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, sorl-thumbnail

I have a django project that works very well and shows all media files uploaded from the admin when `debug = True` but immediately i turn change to `debug = False` django cannot find my media folder yet it loads my static folder. as you can see i have set up my `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` correctly

[image]

And here is my `urls.py` configuration as well

[image]

And in the console logs i find my images output 404 errors while i can clearly see a media folder is present with the images in my directories

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me point out what i am doing wrong or why django can't find my media folder?

Comment: Can you put the code in text? Images are hard to use.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of the reference since my problem is the other way round. my site works in development but my uploaded images in the media folder are not found when `debug = False`

Comment: The +static usage is only for debug/dev mode.  I believe you can fix it setting STATIC_URL and doing collectstatic.  But I am not close to my regular workspace to be sure of it.  I will look later if you don't figure it out.

Comment: i already did collectstatic and the normal css and images are loaded but the uploaded images in media folder aren't found

Answer (score 2):

Django does not processes static files in production mode, you need to call `./manage.py collectstatic` and serve collected static files with web server on the front of your django app.

Or run you dev server with `--insecure` option. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure

Answer (score 2):

Adding this code below to **"urls.py"** displays media files in **"DEBUG = False"**:

```py
# "urls.py"

from  django.conf.urls import url
from  django.views.static import serve
from  django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answer [Media files not showing on Debug False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505292/media-files-not-showing-on-debug-false/42505333#42505333) (" The behaviour you are seeing is by design, Django doesn't serve static files in production mode. Serving many, potentially huge static files using Python will put a lot of stress on the server, while any of the common servers will handle that with ease.")

Otherwise, If I'm right than you want to host your website on a server.
Once you turn debug = True to False, Django no longer handle the static files by itself. Now, it's the server which handles the static files. I have this problem when I uploaded my django project to pythonanywhere. In order to solve the problem, you have to explicitly tell the server where your static files are located:

[image: How to serve static files on pythonanywhere.]

Comment: Better not to post links alone - instead, include the essential information from the link in your answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not ready to deploy your website, if not true, you should  find a way to server your web first, not simply running manage.py runserver, it's just not practical.

One good way to deploy your django website is use  Apache2 and mod_wsgi, in this case, you need to make some configuration with apache server's httpd.conf file, and apache2 will take care of serving files(static,media).

the httpd.conf will look likes this, also make sure to check django doc.

[serving-uploaded-files-in-development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-uploaded-files-in-development)

[serving-file-in-production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

if you are not ready to deploy your website, you should not turn debug to false.

Answer (score 1):

Remove STATICFILES_DIRS within `settings.py` and replace it with

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

when debug = False

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT AT US.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention all of your pages need to include:

```
{% load static %}
```

you have to configure Apache to serve the media files.

You shouldn't use collectstatic for your media dir. Remove '/home/admin/webapps/mainfolder/mainapp/media' from STATICFILES_DIRS, then set

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/admin/webapps/mainfolder/mainapp/media'
```

Once you've done this, the static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) should serve media files when `DEBUG = True`.

For `DEBUG = False`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The media files are loaded when `debug = True` but when i turn it to `false` the images cannot be found. in other words on development it works but in production it doesn't load the images

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example:

**settings.py**

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

if DEBUG:
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else:
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
#other paths

re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + \
           static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```